# How to create model classes in Vue.js and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, extjs, model

I'm struggling to understand how other frameworks, mainly Vue.js and React, model data.  In Ext JS, we define a model using [Ext.data.Model](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.data.Model.html), which gives us "types," properties, associations, methods for fetching the data, encapsulation, etc.  It models what the API returns to the UI and provides a class to manage this data.

In React, I know there's `props` and `state`, but that feels more like configuration values for the view... not actual data modeling.  That leaves me with TypeScript Interfaces or ES6 classes, I think, and I'm leaning more toward TS Interfaces because it provides types, but I don't know if this is the standard approach for these frameworks.

Anyway, if I wanted to create the below model class in Vue.js or React, how would I accomplish this?  Would I use TS Interfaces, ES6 classes, something else, or do these frameworks not care about this?  I'm going to keep the class simple for now, but bonus points if you want to include how associations (one-to-one and one-to-many relationships) are set up... you can see my full response at [this mockaroo link](https://mockaroo.com/8e546360).

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'Id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'UserName',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Age',
        type: 'int'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json'
    }
});
```

Comment: Checkout Redux and Vuex

Comment: Neither Vue nor React have such models as builtins or de facto solutions. They offer very different approaches that are determined by the way they implement reactivity in the first place. Classes won't do any good there because of that. You are free to use TS interfaces for type safety but this isn't related to the implementation. A more close framework-agnostic thing is mobx-state-tree.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I started looking at Redux, and my head started to spin... it seemed like so much for so very little, but I'm sure I'm just fully not understanding its value.  `mobx-state-tree` looks very much like what I'm wanting.  I think the problem that I have with these packages that I'd consider using is survivability... how long will the maintainers of these packages continue to maintain it?